# Get grouped comma separated values with linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects, grouping

I would like a third column "items" with the values that are grouped.

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dic.Add("a", 1);
dic.Add("b", 1);
dic.Add("c", 2);
dic.Add("d", 3);

var dCounts =
    (from i in dic
    group i by i.Value into g
    select new { g.Key, count = g.Count()});

    var a = dCounts.Where(c => c.count>1 );

dCounts.Dump();
a.Dump();
```

This code results in:

```
Key Count
1   2
2   1
3   1
```

I would like these results:

```
Key Count Items
1   2     a, b
2   1     c
3   1     d
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
    var dCounts =
        (from i in dic
            group i by i.Value into g
            select new { g.Key, count = g.Count(), Items = string.Join(",", g.Select(kvp => kvp.Key)) });
```

Use `string.Join(",", {array})`, passing in your array of keys.

Comment: if we use string.Join, then getting exception like Linq to entities doesn't recognize the string.Join method

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var dCounts = 
    from i in dic 
    group i by i.Value into g 
    select new { g.Key, Count = g.Count(), Values = g };
```

The result created by grouping (value `g`) has a property `Key` that gives you the key, but it also implements `IEnumerable<T>` that allows you to access individual values in the group. If you return just `g` then you can iterate over all values using `foreach` or process them using LINQ.

Here is a simple dump function to demonstrate this:

```
foreach(var el in dCounts) {
  Console.Write(" - {0}, count: {1}, values:", el.Key, el.Count);
  foreach(var item in el.Values) Console.Write("{0}, ", item);
|
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from i in dic 
group i.Key by i.Value into g 
select new
{
  g.Key,
  count = g.Count(),
  items = string.Join(",", g.ToArray())
});
```

Comment: It won;t work, cause EF can't recognize a C# method string.Join()

Comment: @LabLab Original question does not involve EF.  If you have a question about EF, go ask it.

Comment: Simply put: I can't help it if the Microsoft Data team can't get on board with language _Integration_.  They made EF its own extra thing with its own dissonance.  We're having a LINQ conversation here, not EF.